# How to avoid duplicate code with generated classes from different packages

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

We generate Java classes based on two XSD files. The classes land in their package respective to the XSD file (a and b). The methods we would like to use of the generated classes are the same. But they don't implement an interface or a super class. We do not have control over the XSD, it's provided.

Example:

```
package code.generated.a;
class X {
  void do() {...}
}

package code.generated.b;
class X {
  void do() {...}
}
```

We would now like to use those classes in our own written code, but would not like to duplicate it.

So as of now we have to consume the interfaces by duplicating the code:

```
package code.ours.a
class Consumer {
  void use(code.generated.a.X x) {...}
}

package code.ours.b
class Consumer {
  void use(code.generated.b.X x) {...}
}
```

What is the recommended way of resolving the duplicate code?

Implicit interfaces of Go come to mind, but we're dealing with Java. Is there a way to this with generics?

Comment: Try to specify the package name to the code generator,  to be the same for both XSD...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you decide on using just one of these package implementations (e.g. 'a.X') in most of your code by extending that version, and in those few places where you must either produce or consume the other (e.g. 'b.X' version), provide a transformation. This can be done in several ways. Following are two possible solutions:

```
package code.ours;
class Consumer extends code.generated.a.X {
    public Consumer() {}
    public Consumer(code.generated.a.X original) {
        setName(original.getName());
    }
    public Consumer(code.generated.b.X original) {
        setName(original.getName());
    }
    public code.generated.b.X getB() {
        code.generated.b.X result = new code.generated.b.X();
        result.setName(this.getName());
        return result;
    }
}
```

or

```
package code.ours;
class Consumer extends code.generated.a.X {
    private code.generated.a.X delegate;
    public Consumer() {
        delegate = new code.generated.a.X delegate();
    }
    public Consumer(code.generated.a.X original) {
        delegate = original;
    }
    public Consumer(code.generated.b.X original) {
        delegate = new code.generated.a.X();
        delegate.setName(original.getName());
    }
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return delegate.getName();
    }
    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        delegate.setName(name);
    }
    public code.generated.b.X getB() {
        code.generated.b.X result = new code.generated.b.X();
        result.setName(this.getName());
        return result;
    }
}
```